# Showing images uploaded via admin

Tags: django

I´m loading images to a model in the admin panel (not in form).

I know it only stores a link. When I try to show the image I does not shows.

I try the following:

```
{% for x in dataset %}
   <img src="{{ x.foto_disco.url }}" alt="Caca" style="width: 100%;">
   <p>{{ x.foto_disco.url }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I try to get the image and then show also the link to see where it´s pointing. The file upload works fine.

It points to the correct myapp/media folder.But still cant see the image in the template.

In the model I have:

```
foto_disco = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True, null=True)
```

In settings I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

I urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I can´t figure out which is the problem. Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting up media and static file handling can be a bit tricky when doing the first time. Can you inspect your `<img>` and check if there's actually any url set? Can you open the image via http://localhost:8000/media/IMAGE.jpg ?

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem becuse of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to test the image directly localhost:8000/media/IMAGE.jpg, I found that was redirected to the home page, not to the image.

So I realized I had a this line at my urls.py file:

```
url('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),
```

I took that line off and now it works perfectly.

Thanks @blacklwhite for the hint.